# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getView' of undefined --> nativescript-couchbase

Tags: angular, nativescript, couchbase

I have a problem with nativescript-couchbase.

I install this plugin with comand: `tns plugin add nativescript-couchbase`
The installation was successfully completed.

But whene I run my app show this error:

[image]

Can you suggest me, what is the problem?

In references.d.ts

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-core-modules/tns-core-modules.d.ts" /> Needed for autocompletion and compilation.
/// <reference path="./node_modules/nativescript-couchbase/couchbase.d.ts" />
```

in my component database.ts

```
import  { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Couchbase } from 'nativescript-couchbase';

Injectable()
export class Database{

    private storage : any;
    private isInstantiated: boolean;

   public constructor(){
       if(!this.isInstantiated){
           this.storage = new Couchbase('myproject');
           this.storage.createView('people','1', (document, emitter)=> {
               emitter.emit(document._id, document);
           });
           this.isInstantiated = true;

       }
   } 
   public getStorage(){
       return this.storage;
   }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post more of the context for your application. How did you import the module? It is hard to debug with just the error stack.

Comment: I'm attending a tutorial online for nativescript, and I'm working on an example. This error appears to me. I edit my post. Thank you

Comment: seems like you are hitting `can not read property AndroidContext ..` https://github.com/couchbaselabs/nativescript-couchbase/issues/73